# MS Detours Library, detouring non win api function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, detours

I want to use the windows detours library to detour a non win api function.  The function is part of the Qt library (QtGui4.dll).  I am wondering how I would set up the function signature for :

```
void QPainter::drawText ( const QPointF & position, const QString & text )
```

I had a go with this and it received my usual share of errors, a little explanation of requirements would be interesting as well:

```
void (QPainter * real_drawText)(const QPointF & position, const QString & text) = drawText
```

This is what they look like for TextOut, under the windows API:

```
BOOL (WINAPI * Real_TextOut)(HDC a0, int a1, int a2, LPCWSTR a3, int a4) = TextOutW;
BOOL WINAPI Mine_TextOut(HDC hdc,int X,int Y,LPCWSTR text,int textLen)
{
BOOL rv = Real_TextOut(hdc, X, Y, text, textLen);

HWND hWindow = WindowFromDC(hdc);

SendTextMessage(hWindow, text);

return rv;
}
```

So, following on from Gene's suggestion I tried:

```
typedef void (QPainter::* Real_qp_drawText)(const QPointF & position, const QString & text);

void Mine_drawText(const QPointF & position, const QString & text)
{

    Real_qp_drawText(position,text);

}
```

But got the error, 'a function-style conversion to a built-in type can only take one parameter.

So anyway, they say a little public humiliation is good for the soul, my soul must be having the best time...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your functions is FnType:

```
typedef void (QPainter::*FnType)(const QPointF &, const QString &);
```

but it looks like what they expect is a `WINIAPI` = `__stdcall` C function instead. You might think if you can wrap your function into a C function.

Comment: Sorry Gene, this is all kind of new to me so i am going to ask, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that non-static member functions do get an implicit `this` pointer as parameter, that you have to declare when detouring.